# R Highcharter: Multi-level drilldown with multiple series

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am trying to create a multi-level drilldown using `Highcharter` that has multiple series in each drilldown (a column and a line marker). I have the one series working but unsure of how to add another one to it. I would like the `goal` dataset to be a point marker (preferable a line) on each category axis and when the user `drilldowns` the `dat` dataset, it shows the layers of the `goal` dataset as well.

I.e. First graph has 3 columns (City, Farm, & Ocean) and a marker at each column showing their goals. When clicking on 'City', it goes to 2 columns (Bus & Car) and a marker at each column showing their goals. Etc.

Below is the code so far:

```
library (tidyr)
library (data.table)
library (highcharter)
library (dplyr)
library (shinydashboard)
library (shiny)

rm(list=ls())

x <- c("Farm","Farm","Farm","Farm","City","City","City","Ocean","Ocean")
y <- c("Sheep","Sheep","Sheep","Cow","Car","Bus","Bus","Boat","Boat")
z <- c("Bill","Bill","Tracy","Sandy","Bob","Carl","Newt","Fig","Tony")
a <- c(20,20,30,10,20,10,50,40,20)

dat <- data.frame(x,y,z,a, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

x <- c("Farm","Farm","Farm","City","City","City","Ocean","Ocean")
y <- c("Sheep","Sheep","Cow","Car","Bus","Bus","Boat","Boat")
z <- c("Bill","Tracy","Sandy","Bob","Carl","Newt","Fig","Tony")
a <- c(5,10,5,0,5,10,5,15)

goal <- data.frame(x,y,z,a, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

header <- dashboardHeader()
body <- dashboardBody(

  highchartOutput("Working")

)
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$Working <- renderHighchart({
    #First Tier Columns
    datSum <- dat %>%
      group_by(x) %>%
      summarize(Quantity = sum(a)
      )
    datSum <- arrange(datSum,desc(Quantity))
    Lvl1dfStatus <- tibble(name = datSum$x, y = datSum$Quantity, drilldown = tolower(name))

    datGoal <- goal %>%
      group_by(x) %>%
      summarize(Quantity = sum(a)
      )
    datGoal <- arrange(datGoal,desc(Quantity))
    Lvl1dfStatus2 <- tibble(name = datGoal$x, y = datGoal$Quantity, drilldown = tolower(datGoal$x))

    #Second Tier Columns
    Level_2_Drilldowns <- lapply(unique(dat$x), function(x_level) {
      datSum2 <- dat[dat$x == x_level,]
      datSum2 <- datSum2 %>%
        group_by(y) %>%
        summarize(Quantity = sum(a)
        )
      datSum2 <- arrange(datSum2,desc(Quantity)) ###CHECK
      Lvl2dfStatus <- tibble(name = datSum2$y, y = datSum2$Quantity, drilldown = tolower(paste(x_level, name, sep = "_")))
      list(id = tolower(x_level), type = "column", data = list_parse(Lvl2dfStatus))
    })

    Level_2_Drilldowns2 <- lapply(unique(goal$x), function(x_level) {
      datGoal2 <- goal[goal$x == x_level,]
      datGoal2 <- datGoal2 %>%
        group_by(y) %>%
        summarize(Quantity = sum(a)
        )
      datGoal2 <- arrange(datGoal2,desc(Quantity)) ###CHECK
      Lvl2dfStatus2 <- tibble(name = datGoal2$y, y = datGoal2$Quantity, drilldown = tolower(paste(x_level, name, sep = "_")))
      list(id = tolower(x_level), type = "scatter", data = list_parse(Lvl2dfStatus2))
    })



    #Third Tier Columns

    Level_3_Drilldowns <- lapply(unique(dat$x), function(x_level) {
      datSum2 <- dat[dat$x == x_level,]
      lapply(unique(datSum2$y), function(y_level) {
        datSum3 <- datSum2[datSum2$y == y_level,]
        datSum3 <- datSum3 %>%
          group_by(z) %>%
          summarize(Quantity = sum(a)
          )
        datSum3 <- arrange(datSum3,desc(Quantity))
        Lvl3dfStatus <- tibble(name = datSum3$z,y = datSum3$Quantity)
        list(id = tolower(paste(x_level, y_level, sep = "_")), type = "column", data = list_parse2(Lvl3dfStatus))
      })
    }) %>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)

    highchart() %>%
      hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
      hc_add_series(Lvl1dfStatus, "column", hcaes(x = name, y = y), color = "#E4551F") %>%
      hc_add_series(Lvl1dfStatus2, "scatter", hcaes(x = name, y = y), color = "#00AB8E") %>%
      hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
      hc_drilldown(
        allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
        series = c(Level_2_Drilldowns2, Level_2_Drilldowns, Level_3_Drilldowns)
      )
  })

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

***EDIT***

To give an example of what it should look like. See the below pictures.

First:
[image]
Second (after clicking on Farm):
[image]
Third (after clicking on Sheep):
[image]

The key is keeping the drilldown of ***both*** `dat` and `goal`. I have the multi-drilldown of `dat` working but I don't know how to incorporate `goal` into it. I am thinking I have to somehow align the drilldown names but unsure of the first steps.

Comment: I dealt with this myself and almost cried after several hours of failure. Have you ever tried Sunbrust D3? Much easier to implement, same information, same technology

Comment: I have not, I don't see how a sunburst visual can help in this example though??

Comment: Hi. Could you somehow simplify your example or explain more precisely, how your drilldown should look like?
Also, do you know pure JavaScript? It would be easier to create chart in jsFiddle first and then just simply rewrite the code to R.
You can base on this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3s0nL6cy

Comment: Hi @raf18seb, I've added some pictures to show how it should look. Unfortunately, I don't know pure JavaScript and I've learned it's not always easy to rewrite it in R.

Comment: @Kevin quick question - what is dat exactly? Separate series? What should happen if we click on the red rectangle?
We can stay here if you wish, but if you'd like, we can go on Highcharts Official Forum - it might be easier to cooperate and exchange information.

Comment: Hi @raf18seb, dat is the main data set (1000's of lines of each unique dat$z in my real situation). goal is a reference data set (1-1 of goal$z and goal$a). Clicking on the red rectangle should either 1) do nothing or 2) act the same as clicking on the blue column and take you to the same drilldown as above. Whichever is easier is fine by me.  No issue where we exchange information, just happy for the help! Whatever is easier for you!

Comment: Ok, I think I understand you now. You know how to do drilldown to ONE SERIES, but you don't know how to do drilldown to TWO SERIES, right? In this case, you need to use "chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);" method. Could you take a look at this example and confirm that this is what you've been trying to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eg7usca6 (click on the "Chrome" column to see 2 series displayed).
If this is it, I will show you how to implement JS code into R.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right!

Comment: Ok, I am implementing simplified R example now ;)

Comment: Actually, could you study this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54300033/r-package-highcharter-how-do-i-drilldown-to-multiple-series-stacked-column-grap/54350733#54350733
You can see how I implemented JS code into R using JS() method.

Please, ask if you have any specific questions.

Comment: Only issue is how I get my data into the charts using JS() since it's reactive in Shiny. Not sure how to implement that.