# How to drill down to the third hierarchy using higherchart package in R?

Tags: r, plot, charts, r-highcharter, drilldown

I want to create a drill down chart. For that, I created a hierarchy. I can drill down to the second level but unfortunately, I cannot drill down to the third level. Following is the working code for the two level drill down.

```
library(rio)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(highcharter)
library(scales)
library(stringr)

    #My Raw data
    Test <- data.frame(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                             "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                   Group_Two = c("AA", "AAA", "AA", "AAA", "AAA", "AA", 
                                 "AA", "AAA", "BB", "BBB", "BB", "BBB", 
                                 "BB", "BBB", "BB", "BBB"),
                   Group_Three = c("AJX", "ABX", "AJX", "ABX", "APX", "ANX", 
                                   "ANX", "APX", "BJX", "BBX", "BJX", "BBX", 
                                   "BPX", "BNX", "BPX", "BNX"),
                   Group_Four = c("TH", "TH", "SW", "SW", "GC", "PB", "JB", 
                                  "NX", "TH", "TH", "SW", "SW", "GC", "PB", 
                                  "JB", "NX"),
                   Value = c(5293, 78225, 33235, 56022, 13056, 6160, 44067, 75529, 
                             95679, 98172, 27159, 77475, 37838, 25897, 88400, 28484))

######################First Hierarchy##########################
First_test_df <- aggregate(Test$Value~Test$Group, Test, FUN = sum)
colnames(First_test_df) <- c("Hierarchy_One", "price")

latest_First_Hierarchy <- First_test_df %>%
          select(c(Group = Hierarchy_One, Value = price)) %>%
          arrange(desc(Value))

######################Second Hierarchy##########################
Second_Test <- Test[,c("Group", "Group_Two", "Value")]

Second_test_df <- aggregate(Second_Test$Value~ Second_Test$Group + Second_Test$Group_Two, Test, FUN = sum)
colnames(Second_test_df) <- c("Hierarchy_One", "Hierarchy_Two", "price")

latest_Second_Hierarchy <- Second_test_df %>%
  select(c(Group = Hierarchy_One, Group_Two = Hierarchy_Two, Value = price)) %>%
  filter(Group %in% latest_First_Hierarchy$Group) %>%
  arrange(Group, desc(Value)) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(Group, desc(Value))

############Drill down to the second level#############
Test_drilldown <-latest_Second_Hierarchy %>%
  group_nest(Group)%>%
  mutate(
    id = Group,
    type = "column",
    data = map(data, mutate, name = Group_Two, y = Value, drilldown = Group_Two),
    data = map(data, list_parse)
  )

###################Chart##################
mygraph <- hchart(
  latest_First_Hierarchy,
  "column",
  hcaes(x = Group, y = Value, name = Group, drilldown = Group),
  name = "Median Home Values",
  colorByPoint = TRUE
)

###############Chart with the first drill down#############
mygraph <- mygraph %>% 
  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = list_parse(Test_drilldown)
  )

mygraph
```

The above code allows me to drill down to the second level. Unfortunately, with the following code the chart does not drill down to the third level:

```
Test <- data.frame(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                             "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                   Group_Two = c("AA", "AAA", "AA", "AAA", "AAA", "AA", 
                                 "AA", "AAA", "BB", "BBB", "BB", "BBB", 
                                 "BB", "BBB", "BB", "BBB"),
                   Group_Three = c("AJX", "ABX", "AJX", "ABX", "APX", "ANX", 
                                   "ANX", "APX", "BJX", "BBX", "BJX", "BBX", 
                                   "BPX", "BNX", "BPX", "BNX"),
                   Group_Four = c("TH", "TH", "SW", "SW", "GC", "PB", "JB", 
                                  "NX", "TH", "TH", "SW", "SW", "GC", "PB", 
                                  "JB", "NX"),
                   Value = c(5293, 78225, 33235, 56022, 13056, 6160, 44067, 75529, 
                             95679, 98172, 27159, 77475, 37838, 25897, 88400, 28484))

######################First Hierarchy##########################
First_test_df <- aggregate(Test$Value~Test$Group, Test, FUN = sum)
colnames(First_test_df) <- c("Hierarchy_One", "price")

latest_First_Hierarchy <- First_test_df %>%
      select(c(Group = Hierarchy_One, Value = price)) %>%
      arrange(desc(Value))

######################Second Hierarchy##########################
Second_Test <- Test[,c("Group", "Group_Two", "Value")]

Second_test_df <- aggregate(Second_Test$Value~ Second_Test$Group + Second_Test$Group_Two, Test, FUN = sum)
colnames(Second_test_df) <- c("Hierarchy_One", "Hierarchy_Two", "price")

latest_Second_Hierarchy <- Second_test_df %>%
      select(c(Group = Hierarchy_One, Group_Two = Hierarchy_Two, Value = price)) %>%
      filter(Group %in% latest_First_Hierarchy$Group) %>%
      arrange(Group, desc(Value)) %>%
      group_by(Group) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      arrange(Group, desc(Value))

####################Third Hierarchy###############################
Third_Test <- Test[,c("Group", "Group_Two", "Group_Three", "Value")]

Third_test_df <- aggregate(Third_Test$Value~ Third_Test$Group + Third_Test$Group_Two + Third_Test$Group_Three, Test, FUN = sum)
colnames(Third_test_df) <- c("Hierarchy_One", "Hierarchy_Two", "Hierarchy_Three", "price")

latest_Third_Hierarchy <- Third_test_df %>%
  select(c(Group_Two = Hierarchy_Two, Group_Three = Hierarchy_Three, Value = price)) %>%
  filter(Group_Two %in% latest_Second_Hierarchy$Group_Two) %>%
  arrange(Group_Two, desc(Value)) %>%
  group_by(Group_Two) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(Group_Two, desc(Value))


Test_drilldown <-latest_Second_Hierarchy %>%
  group_nest(Group)%>%
  mutate(
    id = Group,
    type = "column",
    data = map(data, mutate, name = Group_Two, y = Value, drilldown = Group_Two),
    data = map(data, list_parse)
  )

Test_drilldown_Two <-latest_Third_Hierarchy %>%
  group_nest(Group_Two)%>%
  mutate(
    id = Group_Two,
    type = "column",
    data = map(data, mutate, name = Group_Three, y = Value, drilldown = Group_Three),
    data = map(data, list_parse)
  )

mygraph <- hchart(
  latest_First_Hierarchy,
  "column",
  hcaes(x = Group, y = Value, name = Group, drilldown = Group),
  name = "Median Home Values",
  colorByPoint = TRUE
)

mygraph <- mygraph %>% 
  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = list(list_parse(Test_drilldown), list_parse(Test_drilldown_Two))
  )

mygraph
```

I found that the question similar to this has been asked before (link: [How to make 3 levels drilldown plot in R highcharter (possible other packages)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192825/how-to-make-3-levels-drilldown-plot-in-r-highcharter-possible-other-packages)) but I do not want to type long list of series in hc_drilldown function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After banging my head against the wall for last couple of days, I was able to debug and get the answer. Please find attached code. I would like to thank Kevin for this (source: [R Highcharter: Multi-level drilldown with multiple series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795935/r-highcharter-multi-level-drilldown-with-multiple-series))

```
Test <- data.frame(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                             "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                   Group_Two = c("AA", "AAA", "AA", "AAA", "AAA", "AA", 
                                 "AA", "AAA", "BB", "BBB", "BB", "BBB", 
                                 "BB", "BBB", "BB", "BBB"),
                   Group_Three = c("AJX", "ABX", "AJX", "ABX", "APX", "ANX", 
                                   "ANX", "APX", "BJX", "BBX", "BJX", "BBX", 
                                   "BPX", "BNX", "BPX", "BNX"),
                   Group_Four = c("TH", "TH", "SW", "SW", "GC", "PB", "JB", 
                                  "NX", "TH", "TH", "SW", "SW", "GC", "PB", 
                                  "JB", "NX"),
                   Value = c(5293, 78225, 33235, 56022, 13056, 6160, 44067, 75529, 
                             95679, 98172, 27159, 77475, 37838, 25897, 88400, 28484))

TestSum <- Test %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(Quantity = sum(Value)
  )

TestSum <- arrange(TestSum,desc(Quantity))

Lvl1dfStatus <- tibble(name = TestSum$Group, y = TestSum$Quantity, drilldown = tolower(name))

Level_2_Drilldowns_Test <- lapply(unique(Test$Group), function(x_level) {
  TestSum2 <- subset(Test, Test$Group %in% x_level)
  #TestSum2 <- Test[Test$Group == x_level,]
  TestSum2 <- TestSum2 %>%
    group_by(Group_Two) %>%
    summarize(Quantity = sum(Value)
    )
  TestSum2 <- arrange(TestSum2,desc(Quantity)) ###CHECK
  Lvl2dfStatus <- tibble(name = TestSum2$Group_Two, y = TestSum2$Quantity, drilldown = tolower(paste(x_level, name, sep = "_")))
  list(id = tolower(x_level), type = "column", data = list_parse(Lvl2dfStatus))
})

Level_3_Drilldowns_Test <- lapply(unique(Test$Group), function(x_level) {
  TestSum2 <- subset(Test, Test$Group %in% x_level)
  #TestSum2 <- Test[Test$Group == x_level,]
  lapply(unique(TestSum2$Group_Two), function(y_level) {
    TestSum3 <- subset(TestSum2, TestSum2$Group_Two %in% y_level)
    #TestSum3 <- TestSum2[TestSum2$Group_Two == y_level,]
    TestSum3 <- TestSum3 %>%
      group_by(Group_Three) %>%
      summarize(Quantity = sum(Value)
      )
    TestSum3 <- arrange(TestSum3,desc(Quantity))
    Lvl3dfStatus <- tibble(name = TestSum3$Group_Three,y = TestSum3$Quantity, drilldown = tolower(paste(x_level, y_level, name, sep = "_")))
    list(id = tolower(paste(x_level, y_level, sep = "_")), type = "column", data = list_parse(Lvl3dfStatus))
  })
})%>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)

Level_4_Drilldowns <- lapply(unique(Test$Group), function(x_level) {
  TestSum2 <- subset(Test, Test$Group %in% x_level)
  #TestSum2 <- Test[Test$Group == x_level,]
  lapply(unique(TestSum2$Group_Two), function(y_level) {
    TestSum3 <- subset(TestSum2, TestSum2$Group_Two %in% y_level)
    #TestSum3 <- TestSum2[TestSum2$Group_Two == y_level,]
    lapply(unique(TestSum3$Group_Three), function(z_level) {
      TestSum4 <- subset(TestSum3, TestSum3$Group_Three %in% z_level)
      #TestSum4 <- TestSum3[TestSum3$Group_Three == z_level,]
      TestSum4 <- TestSum4 %>%
        group_by(Group_Four) %>%
        summarize(Quantity = sum(Value)
                  )
      TestSum4 <- arrange(TestSum4,desc(Quantity))
      Lvl4dfStatus <- tibble(name = TestSum4$Group_Four,y = TestSum4$Quantity)
      list(id = tolower(paste(x_level, y_level, z_level, sep = "_")), type = "column", data = list_parse2(Lvl4dfStatus))
  })
  })%>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)
}) %>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)

highchart() %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_add_series(Lvl1dfStatus, "column", hcaes(x = name, y = y), color = "#E4551F") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = c(Level_2_Drilldowns_Test, Level_3_Drilldowns_Test, Level_4_Drilldowns)
  )
```