# Highcharter drilldown with multiple yAxis

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

With the following chart:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "waterfall") %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(create_yaxis(naxis = 2, heights = c(2, 2))) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = c(1,3,2), yAxis = 0) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = c(20, 40, 10), yAxis = 1)
```

How add a drilldown for `yAxis = 0` and other drilldown for `yAxis = 1` ?

Comment: Hi. You can rely on these examples of drilldown in R:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57845118/drilldown-to-multiple-series-from-different-groups-highcharter-in-r/57856347#57856347
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54300033/r-package-highcharter-how-do-i-drilldown-to-multiple-series-stacked-column-grap/54350733#54350733

Please, analyze them and ask if you have any specific question.

Comment: @raf18seb could you please help  with this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431981/how-to-create-two-independent-drill-down-plot-using-highcharter